# Proving Properties and Calculating the Commensurator of Subgroups in $\mathrm{GL}_{2}^{+}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, equivalence-relations, modular-forms

I have a multi-part question involving commensurability and the commensurator of subgroups in a group $G$ and I would love your suggestions/edits/corrections to my workings!

Question: Let $G$ be a group. For two subgroups $\Gamma_{1}, \Gamma_{2}$ recall what it means for $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$ to be commensurable. Further recall the definition of the commensurator $\widetilde{\Gamma_{1}}$ of $\Gamma_{1}$ in $G$. (These are Definitions 5.1.1 and 5.1.2 in the lecture notes.)

a) Show that being commensurable defines an equivalence relation on subgroups of $G$.

b) Let $\Gamma \subseteq G$ be a subgroup. Show that the commensurator, $\widetilde{\Gamma}$, of $\Gamma$ in $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.

c) Let $G=\mathrm{GL}_{2}^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\Gamma=\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$. Compute the commensurator of $\Gamma$ in $G .\left(\right.$ Note that $\left.\mathrm{GL}_{2}^{+}(\mathbb{R})=\left\{g \in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{R}): \operatorname{det}(g)>0\right\}.\right)$

My Solutions: (a) Let's recall the definitions of commensurable subgroups and commensurators before proceeding.

Two subgroups $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ of a group $G$ are said to be commensurable if the intersection $\Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_2$ has finite index in both $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$. Here, the index of a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$, denoted $[G: H]$, is the number of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. We are asked to show that being commensurable defines an equivalence relation on subgroups of $G$. Recall that an equivalence relation must satisfy three properties: reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity.
a) Reflexivity: A subgroup $\Gamma_1$ is commensurable with itself because $\Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_1=\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_1$ clearly has finite index in itself.
b) Symmetry: If $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are commensurable, then $\Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_2$ has finite index in both $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$. Therefore, $\Gamma_2$ is also commensurable with $\Gamma_1$.
c) Transitivity: If $\Gamma_1$ is commensurable with $\Gamma_2$, and $\Gamma_2$ is commensurable with $\Gamma_3$, then $\Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_2$ has finite index in $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$, and $\Gamma_2 \cap \Gamma_3$ has finite index in $\Gamma_2$ and $\Gamma_3$. Therefore, $\Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_3=\left(\Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_2\right) \cap$ $\left(\Gamma_2 \cap \Gamma_3\right)$ has finite index in $\Gamma_1$, since the index $\left[\Gamma_1: \Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_3\right]$ is at most $\left[\Gamma_1: \Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_2\right] \cdot\left[\Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_2: \Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_3\right]$, both of which are finite. Similarly, $\Gamma_1 \cap \Gamma_3$ has finite index in $\Gamma_3$. So, $\Gamma_1$ is commensurable with $\Gamma_3$.
Thus, commensurability is an equivalence relation on the set of subgroups of $G$.

The commensurator $\widetilde{\Gamma_1}$ of $\Gamma_1$ in $G$ is defined as the set of all elements $g \in G$ such that $g \Gamma_1 g^{-1}$ is commensurable with $\Gamma_1$.

(b) To prove that the commensurator $\widetilde{\Gamma}$ of a subgroup $\Gamma$ in $G$ is a subgroup of $G$, we need to show that it satisfies the following properties:

1. Identity: The identity element $e \in G$ must be in $\widetilde{\Gamma} .2$. Closure: If $g_1, g_2 \in \widetilde{\Gamma}$, then their product $g_1 g_2$ must also be in $\widetilde{\Gamma}$. 3 . Inverses: For every $g \in \widetilde{\Gamma}$, its inverse $g^{-1}$ must also be in $\widetilde{\Gamma}$.
   We proceed to demonstrate these three properties:
2. Identity: By definition, $e \Gamma e^{-1}=\Gamma$, and $\Gamma$ is commensurable with itself, so $e \in \widetilde{\Gamma}$.
3. Closure: Suppose $g_1, g_2 \in \widetilde{\Gamma}$. This means $g_1 \Gamma g_1^{-1}$ and $g_2 \Gamma g_2^{-1}$ are commensurable with $\Gamma$. We have
   $$
   \left(g_1 g_2\right) \Gamma\left(g_1 g_2\right)^{-1}=g_1\left(g_2 \Gamma g_2^{-1}\right) g_1^{-1}
   $$
   Since $g_1 \Gamma g_1^{-1}$ is commensurable with $\Gamma$, and conjugation is an automorphism (i.e., it preserves the group structure), it follows that $g_1\left(g_2 \Gamma g_2^{-1}\right) g_1^{-1}$ is commensurable with $\Gamma$. Thus, $g_1 g_2 \in \widetilde{\Gamma}$.
4. Inverses: Suppose $g \in \widetilde{\Gamma}$. Then, $g \Gamma g^{-1}$ is commensurable with $\Gamma$. We want to show that $g^{-1} \Gamma g$ is also commensurable with $\Gamma$. Notice that $g^{-1} \Gamma g=\left(g \Gamma g^{-1}\right)^{-1}$. Since inverses and taking the inverse are both automorphisms, we conclude that $g^{-1} \Gamma g$ is commensurable with $\Gamma$. Therefore, $g^{-1} \in \widetilde{\Gamma}$.
   So, the commensurator $\widetilde{\Gamma}$ satisfies all properties of a subgroup and is thus a subgroup of $G$.

(c) The group $\mathrm{GL}_2^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ is the group of $2 \times 2$ real matrices with positive determinant, and $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is the special linear group of $2 \mathrm{x} 2$ integer matrices with determinant 1 .

To compute the commensurator of $\Gamma=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ in $G=\mathrm{GL}_2^{+}(\mathbb{R})$, we want to find all $g \in G$ such that $g \Gamma g^{-1}$ is commensurable with $\Gamma$.

Let $g=\left(\begin{array}{ll}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right) \in G$, so that $g \Gamma g^{-1}$ consists of all matrices of the form $g \gamma g^{-1}$ for $\gamma \in \Gamma$. We can compute this explicitly as: $$
g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
m & n \\
p & q
\end{array}\right) g^{-1}=\frac{1}{a d-b c}\left(\begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
m & n \\
p & q
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
d & -b \\
-c & a
\end{array}\right)
$$
for all $m, n, p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $m q-n p=1$.
The resulting group $g \Gamma g^{-1}$ is commensurable with $\Gamma$ if and only if it is a discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ (the reason being that $\Gamma$ itself is a discrete subgroup, and two discrete subgroups are commensurable if and only if they have a common discrete subgroup, which must be of finite index in each).

It is a classic result in the theory of modular forms that $g \Gamma g^{-1}$ is a discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if the entries of $g$ are all rational numbers and $\operatorname{det}(g)= \pm 1$.
Therefore, the commensurator of $\Gamma$ in $G$ is the group
$$
\widetilde{\Gamma}=\left\{g=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right) \in \mathrm{GL}_2^{+}(\mathbb{R}): a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q} \text { and } a d-b c= \pm 1\right\} .
$$

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Part (c) of this question is much harder than (a) and (b), and I strongly recommend making sure you're secure on the two initial parts before you attack the much harder final part. To get some intuition for (c), you might want to write down explicitly what $g \Gamma g^{-1}$ looks like when $g = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 17\end{pmatrix}$, or $g = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: (Incidentally, this question looks familiar, did it come from a Warwick modular forms coursework sheet by any chance?)

Comment: Hi @DavidLoeffler, thanks a lot for your comment, very helpful! No, I am based in Bonn but that's quite interesting to hear. Perhaps our course was motivated by the one in Warwick or vice-versa?